# Too much waitforelement

Tags: selenium

Is it really necessary using `waitForElement` or another wait... if I test javascript single page application with loaded by ajax states? I must precede every action (eg: click,type) by `waitForElement`.

Comment: What else do you expect to do? With Ajax, things will not always happen synchronously, a page might fire a request off and not get something back until a minute later, and then this response causes a button to appear. What else can do you apart from constantly polling the page?

Comment: It's entirely valid http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#the-andwait-commands but in my test every line before action is waitFor...

Comment: I guess that's why some Selenium users hate Ajax, but that's not Selenium's fault ;)

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is necessary for Ajax. But it is not a problem if you use "don't repeat yourself" principle. You should create method like this:

```
clickWithExplicitWait(lctr) {
    waitForElementPresent(lctr)//uses ajax wait timeout
    driver.click(lctr)//uses implicit wait timeout
}
```

driver.click() uses implicit wait. So you can specify a different timeouts for implicit wait and for explicit "element wait".
You can implement waitForElementPresent() or other similar methods using org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions package.

If you need to wait for another element to appear after action, use something like:

```
clickAndWait(lctrToClick, lctrToWait) {
    driver.click(lctrToClick)
    waitForElementPresent(lctrToWait)
}
```